# Tomcat REST services not deployed with Intellij IDEA

Tags: rest, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I have just switched to Intellij Idea (11) and I'm having possibly simple problem for which I cannot find a solution within Intellij IDE. I have a web application which contains some classes marked with annotations from `javax.ws.rs` like eg. `@Path("/members")` etc and my  `web.xml` file configured for handling REST calls.

The application is build with Maven, when I package the application either from command line or through the Intellij IDE and copy the `.war` file into tomcat `webapps` directory manually, all works fine, eg. I can access `GET` based services from the browser.

If I deploy the application through configured tomcat in Intellij IDE the application works but without the REST portion, so I'm not able to execute any rest based calls (all end up with 404 error). I cannot see anything in logs about deploying rest service classes like I do during manual deployment:

```
INFO: Adding scanned resource: com.softberries.klerk.rest.MemberResourceRESTService
```

so its definitively an IDE configuration option I've missed which prevents tomcat from scanning classes for this annotations.

The question is how should I configure my Tomcat within the IDE to work the same as started manually.

Comment: Did you check the artifact configuration? Does it product the same war as Maven?

Comment: Thats the point, if i package it either through the IDE or with 'mvn' from command line and deploy it manually all works as expected, but if I deploy with IDE no rest services. I can see in the IDE console that its deploying its own '/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml' file, cannot find though where I can configure it in Intellij idea to not modify the war or publish additional files to tomcat

Comment: By default IDEA indeed deploys the app by providing its own ROOT.xml file pointing to the war file instead of copying the war to 'webapps' folder. You can change 'output path' in the artifact configuration in 'Project Structure' dialog to copy the war to 'webapps' folder and remove the artifact from 'Deployment' tab of the Tomcat run configuration to suppress the default behavior.

Comment: I can't find at all where IntelliJ deploys that application to. The console says that the application is deployed but where is it? What URL do I go to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Intellij you need to expose the classes as web services from Tools > WebServices.
Also check that in Setting > Web Services, the prefix path for web service is correct (by default is /services).

Here you have a nice tutorial about how to create webservices in intellij.

http://www.academia.edu/4526516/Creating_Web_Services_Applications_with_IntelliJ_IDEA

By the way... when you do a deploy from intellij, the application goes to:

C:\Users\userName.IntelliJIdea10\system\tomcat\NameDeploy"

This info appears in the console as: "Using CATALINA_BASE": .../path...

Hope this helps,
Cheers